# how to remove invalid launch configuration from recent launches drop-down

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I'm currently developing an Eclipse plug-in that adds its custom launch configurations, which are linked to certain Resources in the workbench.

**Background:** sometimes, the underlying Resource would change, making the launch configuration invalid, and should not be runnable

**How do I programatically remove a launch configuration from the recent launches drop down?**

I mean this little downward facing arrow:

[image]

This would show all the recent launch configurations that were launched recently.

EDIT: I'm currently trying to access the history via the [LaunchConfigurationManager](https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/eclipse-doc36/org/eclipse/debug/internal/ui/launchConfigurations/LaunchConfigurationManager.html#getLaunchHistory(java.lang.String)) and I can't seem to find an API that can tell me where I can get the proper instance, currently everything is null.

SECOND EDIT: The LaunchConfigurationManager is part of an internal package, it should not be used.

Comment: Do you want to remove the launch configuration entirely (i.e. delete it) or just remove it form the launch history?

Comment: just remove from launch history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reflect the deletion of a `Resource` it needs to be linked with the launch configuration, using `ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy.setMappedResources(IResource[])`

Afterwards, when you delete this resource from the workspace (whether also on disk or not) this will hide the launch configuration that has this resource mapped to it.

My solution was to include that method call in the `performApply()` method of the used `AbstractLaunchConfigurationTab`

Link for the [ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy API](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fdebug%2Fcore%2FILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy.html) where I found this

P.S. Now when a resource is deleted (but not on disk, you can try this with a Project with regards to a normal Java Launch Configuration) and then re-added, the launch configuration is back up with all past details

Answer (score 1):

> Background: sometimes, the underlying Resource would change, making the launch configuration invalid, and should not be runnable

Why would you want to remove an 'invalid' launch configuration from the history but leave it intact otherwise? If it is invalid, remove it entirely or *repair* it. But that's just my two cents without knowing the details of your application.

If you are willing to take the risk and use internal API you should be able to get the `LaunchHistory` via `DebugUIPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchConfigurationManager()lgetLaunchHistory()`.

But have you tried to remove and re-add the invalid launch configuration right away to just remove it from the history?

```java
ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy workingCopy = launchConfig.getWorkingCopy();
workingCopy.delete();
ILaunchConfigurationType launchType = launchConfig.getType();
IContainer container = launchConfig.getFile() == null ? null : launchConfig.getFile().getParent();
ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy newLaunchConfig = launchType.newInstance( container, workingCopy.getName() );
// copy all attributes from 'launchConfig' to 'newLaunchConfig'
newLaunchConfig.doSave();
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion of just deleting the launch config. I will try the removing solution and let you know

Comment: I've tried this, doesn't seem to work. Albeit I have used launchConfig.getType() instead of DebugPlugin.getDefault.getLaunchManager().getLaunchConfigurationType(...); Was that actually necessary?

Comment: Indeed, `launchConfig.getType()` is the better choice. But what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: it is not deleted from the history

Comment: it seems like mapping the Resource to the launch configuration deals with this automagically, just like with every other usual Run Configuration (and should the project be deleted [not on disk] and re-introduced, the Run Configuration will be regenerated as well)